# How to pass custom props and history to Route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, components, react-router-dom

How to I get access to the history function when passing custom props to component.

```
<Route path="/" exact component={<Home prop1={this.state.example}/>}/>
```

If I try getting the history object in Home component, I can't get to use the history functions. I logged the history object in the console and I can see there's not `push` or `replace` functions anymore.

Where as, using this

```
<Route path="/" exact component={Home}/>
```

works perfecting except then I can't pass my custom props.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to use the Spread operators and pass your custom props alongside.

```
 <Route exact path="/" component={props => <Home props={{ data: "check", ...props }}/>}/>
```

If you console the props inside Home component, you can see the value of data in props.data

Comment: Thanks, this works. 

I assumed the function param was the history object.

A quick correction, ```<Route exact path="/" component={props => <Home data="check" {...props }/>}/>``` else you will have to access the history object like so ```{props.props.history}```